# Is there an open source Http proxy written in C#?

Tags: c#, http-proxy

Does anyone know a Http proxy source code written in C#? I want a proxy to write a proxy that will filter the response and forward it to the client! I have been referring to the Mentalis project and it seems like their proxy doesn't work in multi-threaded environment!

Anyone knows a multi-threaded http proxy server open source project ?

Comment: Why is c# part of your requirement? And is there a programming part of your question?

Answer (score 0):

[FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) is what I use.

Comment: @AkashKava: Actually, there is a free version.  And back in 2011, when this answer was first posted, there were no for-pay versions of FiddlerCore.

Comment: Yes, it is no longer free for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make what you need by forking this 
https://github.com/mcintyre321/WebAPI-Proxy

Answer (score 0):

http/https reverse proxy with full source - assembly code that can be linked to any exe. comes with sample forms and service projects

https://github.com/CalypsoSys/Babalu_rProxy

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

This one is complete source code with SSL proxy.